# Find a unit speed parametrization of the semicubical parabola $t\to\left(t^{2},t^{3}\right)$, valid for $t>0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves, parametrization, arc-length

This is Chapter 1.1, Problem 7 of Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica, by Alfred Gray, et al.

> Find a unit speed parametrization of the semicubical parabola $t\to\left(t^{2},t^{3}\right)$, valid for $t>0.$

They give this expression for the unit tangent vector.

> In seeking a unit speed parametrization of $sc\left(t\right)=\left(t^{2},t^{3}\right),$  a computation shows that

$$\frac{sc^{\prime}\left(t\right)}{\left\Vert sc^{\prime}\left(t\right)\right\Vert }=\frac{\left(t^{2},t^{3}\right)}{\sqrt{t^{2}\left(4+9t^{2}\right)}}.$$

This fairly trivial computation is the square root of

$$ds^{2}=dx^{2}+dy^{2}=(2tdt)^{2}+\left(3t^{2}dt\right)^{2}=t^{2}\left(4+9t^{2}\right)dt^{2}.$$

I can also find this expression for arc length as a function of $t$

$$s\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{27}\left(9t^{2}+4\right)^{3/2}-\frac{8}{27},$$

which is given in the book, obtainable using Mathematica, and derivable using hyperbolic trigonometric substitution.

But, Mathematica tells me there is no closed form inverse, giving $t$ as a function of $s,$ which is what I would expect a unit speed parametrization would be.  Is there such a closed form solution?

I'm wondering if all they are really asking for is the computation I provided above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s$ looks completely invertible – peel one function off at a time:
$$t=\sqrt{(((27(s+8/27))^{2/3}-4)/9}$$
$$t=\frac{\sqrt{(27s+8)^{2/3}-4}}3$$

Comment: I wrote an answer before seeing yours. At least I can contribute [an animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0a1J.gif).

Comment: I shouldn't have thrown in the towel so early.  But, I got another person's perspective on how to solve this problem.  I don't get that working in isolation.